# Azure Data Factory - read XML column as plain text from Dynamics CRM source

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to read in a table from Dynamics CRM in Azure Data Factory Dataflow, where one column contains XML elements. I don't want to parse this column, but just read it as a plain text. Until now I was not able to do that. The Projection interprets the column as string, but when I try to preview the data, it returns no result.

[image]
Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: Would a projection "cast to string" help, before the sink step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to use a **copy activity** instead of a **data flow activity**, then you can copy HTML data properly.